# Swift. How is it possible to get the name of an instance of a class within another class

Tags: swift

Could the Swift Jedi help me, I'm new to Swift.

There is class A and class B.
Is it possible to get the name (*var **name** = Class A()* ) of an instance of class A in the code of class B, which would then be added to the array.

Comment: Not really and why would you want it, what is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: Instances don't have names (unless you add one, like `let name: String`). What you've highlighted is a name of variable, which stores a _reference_ to an object. That reference can be one of many, and they can each have a different name. That is to say: instances do have one single name based off where you assign them.

Comment: I'm thinking how to make only one function. 
The function will create an instance of another ->
 
class AA {
   var id: Int,
   var name: String
} ->

Adds this instance to the array that the class instance contains ->

class BB {
   var color: String,
   var baseParam: [AA]
}
 and then access the class instance property -> like var frstBB = class BB(), frstBB.basePara.someName.id

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class of an object, using [`type(of: ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/type(of:)). Example:

```
class A {
    func test() {
        print (type(of: self))
    }
}
class B : A{
}
let a = A()
a.test()
let b = B()
b.test()
```

However, this information is available only at runtime and not at compile time.  You may for example display the name of the class.  But you cannot dynamically create an array or a variable of that class.

If you need this, you need to design your classes using some kind of polymorphism. If all the classes have a base class in common, you can just define an array of the base class.  If not, you may consider letting the classes of your design share some common protocol:

```
protocol MySpecs {
    func test()
}
class AA : MySpecs {
...
}
class BB : MySpecs {
...
}

var mylist = [ MySpecs ]()
mylist.append(AA())
mylist.append(BB())
for x in mylist {
    x.test()
}
```

There are [other possibilities](https://swiftsenpai.com/swift/understanding-some-and-any/). But unless you provide more details it'll be difficult to be more specific in the recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advice))

I wanted to do that one function could do two actions. 
Create an instance of another class >> class AA { var id: Int, var name: String } >> and Adds this instance to the array that the class instance contains >> class BB { var color: String, var baseParam: [AA] } >> and then access the class instance property >> like var frstBB = class BB(), frstBB.basePara.someName.id 

Probably I need to think better about the design of the class or another implementation of this action